# Перемещение по якорным ссылкам в горизонтали

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

коллеги. Имеется следующая задача: внутри контейнера друг за другом по горизонтали располагаются столбцы, выходящие за экран и образующие прокрутку. Каждому элементу (столбцу) присвоен айди. Также имеются якорные ссылки, каждая привязанная к соответствующему элементу. Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку был переход к нужному элементу (это получилось) и нужно, чтобы он стоял в начале экрана (с этим проблема). То есть, при перемещении по якорям в горизонтали, я получаю искомый элемент в самой правой части экрана, что естественно не годится. Заранее благодарю за дельные мысли.

```css
.content  {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 200vw;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 10;
  text-align: center;
}

.alphabet {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.alphabet li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: tomato;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block" id="a">a</div>
    <div class="block" id="b">b</div>
    <div class="block" id="c">c</div>
    <div class="block" id="d">d</div>
    <div class="block" id="e">e</div>
    <div class="block" id="f">f</div>
    <div class="block" id="g">g</div>
    <div class="block" id="h">h</div>
    <div class="block" id="i">i</div>
    <div class="block" id="j">j</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="alphabet">
    <li><a href="#a">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">d</a></li>
    <li><a href="#e">e</a></li>
    <li><a href="#f">f</a></li>
    <li><a href="#g">g</a></li>
    <li><a href="#h">h</a></li>
    <li><a href="#i">i</a></li>
    <li><a href="#j">j</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: добавьте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Roman зачем пытаться изобретать слайдер?) если они уже есть. А если по делу тогда что мешается вам чекать ширину допустим боди? и сдвигать ваш столбец на данное расстояние

Comment: @Дмытрык, да, конечно: https://codepen.io/drsg/pen/vYEKyWv

Comment: @Yamich, а чем сдвигать после того, как зачекал боди? Я просто в js только первые шаги делаю.

Comment: @Дмытрык, вот я ещё не придумал, что именно в js должно быть

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так надо?

```js
function gotoelement(e_id) {
  document.getElementById('papa').scrollLeft = document.getElementById(e_id).offsetLeft - document.getElementById('papa').offsetLeft - document.getElementById('papa').clientLeft;
  return false;
}
```

```css
.papa {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.son {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="papa" id="papa">
  <div class="son" id="s1">son 1</div>
  <div class="son" id="s2">son 2</div>
  <div class="son" id="s3">son 3</div>
  <div class="son" id="s4">son 4</div>
  <div class="son" id="s5">son 5</div>
  <div class="son" id="s6">son 6</div>
</div>
<hr>
<a nav="s1" onclick="gotoelement(this.getAttribute('nav'))">to son 1</a>
<a nav="s2" onclick="gotoelement(this.getAttribute('nav'))">to son 2</a>
<a nav="s3" onclick="gotoelement(this.getAttribute('nav'))">to son 3</a>
<a nav="s4" onclick="gotoelement(this.getAttribute('nav'))">to son 4</a>
<a nav="s5" onclick="gotoelement(this.getAttribute('nav'))">to son 5</a>
<a nav="s6" onclick="gotoelement(this.getAttribute('nav'))">to son 6</a>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это то что надо!